# Mozilla display Problem with javascript

Tags: javascript

I n an aspx page I am using a javascript function like

function ReverseResult()
{

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtIncrementAmount").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNewCTC").value) - parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=lblCurrentCTC.ClientID %>').innerText);
var result;
result = parseInt(document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtIncrementAmount").value)*100 / parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=lblCurrentCTC.ClientID %>').innerText);

 if(result == "Infinity")
 {        
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtIncrementPerc").value = 100.00;
 } 
 else
 {    
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtIncrementPerc").value = result.toFixed(2);
 }
```

}

This works fine in IE. But in the mozilla the result display as Nan

Pls help to solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `innerText` to `innerHTML`

From the [docs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/migrate_apps_from_internet_explorer_to_mozilla):

> Mozilla also supports Internet
>   Explorer's innerHTML method, which it
>   can call on almost any node. It does
>   not, however, support outerHTML (which
>   adds markup around an element, and has
>   no standard equivalent) and innerText
>   (which sets the text value of the
>   node, and which you can achieve in
>   Mozilla by using textContent).

Comment: Thanks . Now its working fine when I change innerText to innerHTML